# Product are getting deleted for no reason

Tags: product, delete, magento2.4.3.p1

Some of my products are getting deleted for no reason
I am importing my products with an Api

> [2022-10-17 01:11:39] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:
> {"method":"DELETE","url":"https://mathiassports.com/rest/V1/products/MMDB-7-32302d30323936","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_29899"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}}
> []

I have a lot of log in the debug.log file but i dont know why
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

look at your request

```
{"method":"DELETE","url":"https://mathiassports.com/rest/V1/products/MMDB-7-32302d30323936","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["cat_p_29899"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}}
```

You are using 'DELETE' method

Comment: The thing is i'm not doing this request.
The problem is i don't know why it's doing by itself

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you choose **Delete** behavior, it will delete your products.
- Or you choose **Replace** behavior, and you already have products that same SKU, it will create new products and remove old products.

Comment: I'm not importing my product like that.
I'm using an API